# How to add DatePicker to my MVC3 C# site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor, datepicker

I've been trying to figure out how to do this all afternoon, but can't seem to get a grip on how to get DatePicker to work with my site.

Also, if possible I would like to remove the Time part of the DateTime, as I'm only interested in the Date the entry gets posted.

I've included the code so far below, I've pretty much removed everything I've attempted so far so it is back to the beginning. I've referenced the JQuery files at the top of _Layout.cshtml which I think is correct.

I've looked at many guides on the web, but struggled to make much sense of them, although I will keep reading.

I've added these lines to the top of my _Layout.cshtml (I've also unpacked and copied the JQuery folders to the locations referenced below as well)

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/minified/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My View code looks like this:

```
@model dale_harrison.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>News</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.News_Entry)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Entry)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.News_Entry)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.News_Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date)*@
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date, new object{ id = "news_date" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.News_Date)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#news_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
</script>
```

My Model is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace dale_harrison.Models
{
    public class News
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string News_Entry { get; set; } 
        public DateTime News_Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewsDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<News> News_Entries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone for helping

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this first:

Add your html code without the html helper:

```
<input type="text" id="news_date" name="news_date" />
```

Or, if you want to add the `id` with the Html helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date, new { id = "news_date" } )
```

And then add this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#news_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
```

You can try this first to check if you have set it all the configuration in your project correctly. You should solve your problem with those lines.

After you get this working in your site, read about html helpers and how to encapsulate code so you do not have to rewrite this everytime.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much Cacho, this part is working, I have a plain old textbox which when I click on it the DatePicker UI pops up successfully.

Comment: Great @Harry! I think you should consider upvoting the answer you like the most and select as an answer to your question too, it does not need to be my answer, pick the best...

Comment: Sorry, one more bit of help if you don't mind? How do I re-write this bit in the View  `<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.News_Date)
        </div>` so that I can reference the TextBox with DatePicker?

Comment: Check the EditorFor overloading, it should be something like this: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.News_Date, new object{ id = "news_date" } ) because you need to add an html id to your element.

Comment: Thanks Cacho, I didn't know how to add an HTML ID to that line - I do now though :-) EDIT: I'm getting a couple of errors for the above with "CreationDate" and "id" (the id throws this: CS0117: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'id')

Comment: @Harry, can you post your code, may be update your question with this? That way will be more easy for me to try to help you...

Comment: thanks, sorry for the delay, I am just updating the code in the question now. This should be exactly what I have right now.

Comment: ...@cacho I should add, it is "id" part that is flagging an error in Visual Studio - screenshot shown here: [Screenshot](http://www.zen87038.zen.co.uk/image/Capture.JPG)

Comment: @Harry, I've updated my answer now, can you try that and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 1):

On the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder you need to create a template for DateTime types, so every time you use `@Html.EditorFor` MVC display whatever you define on your Template

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to hide the time from the text box so that you see "08/11/2007" as opposed to "08/11/2007 00:00:00".

To do this, add "[DataType(DataType.Date)]" to your news class as below;

```
public class News
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string News_Entry { get; set; } 
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime News_Date { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EditorFor neglects extra attributes. Either use TextBoxFor or write EditorFor template...